# "List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();" do not compiles

Tags: java

I've posted a question on how to read from a file and return a random word from that file, and everyone keeps telling me use "List words = new ArrayList();" I did try to use it and it doesnt work!

I've tried everything! i'm very new at java, for i'm still a student! so the internet is my last option, text books are useless...

all i want to do is return a random string from that file and then use it as the guessing word

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.*;

public final class Hangman extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    int i = 0;
    static JPanel panel;
    static JPanel panel2;
    static JPanel panel3;
    static JPanel panel4;

    public Hangman() {
        JButton[] buttons = new JButton[26];

        panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 9));
        panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel3 = new JPanel();
        panel4 = new JPanel();

        JButton btnRestart = new JButton("Restart");
        btnRestart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            }
        });

        JButton btnNewWord = new JButton("Add New Word");
        btnNewWord.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("Words.txt", true);
                    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw, true);

                    String word = JOptionPane
                            .showInputDialog("Please enter a word: ");

                    pw.println(word);
                    pw.close();
                } catch (IOException ie) {
                    System.out.println("Error Thrown" + ie.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });

        JButton btnHelp = new JButton("Help");
        btnHelp.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String message = "The word to guess is represented by a row of dashes, giving the number of letters and category of the word. \nIf the guessing player suggests a letter which occurs in the word, the other player writes it in all its correct positions. \nIf the suggested letter does not occur in the word, the other player draws one element of the hangman diagram as a tally mark."
                        + "\n"
                        + "\nThe game is over when:"
                        + "\nThe guessing player completes the word, or guesses the whole word correctly"
                        + "\nThe other player completes the diagram";
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message, "Help",
                        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
        });

        JButton btnExit = new JButton("Exit");
        btnExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        JLabel lblWord = new JLabel();

        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(
                "D:\\Varsity College\\Prog212Assign1_10-013803\\images\\Hangman1.jpg");
        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        label.setIcon(icon);
        String b[] = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K",
                "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W",
                "X", "Y", "Z" };
        for (i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            buttons[i] = new JButton(b[i]);

            panel.add(buttons[i]);
        }

        panel2.add(label);

        panel3.add(btnRestart);
        panel3.add(btnNewWord);
        panel3.add(btnHelp);
        panel3.add(btnExit);

        panel4.add(lblWord);
    }

    public void readWord() {
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                    "Words.txt"));
            String line = reader.readLine();
            List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
            while (line != null) {
                String[] wordsLine = line.split(" ");
                for (String word : wordsLine) {
                    words.add(word);
                }
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
            Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
            String randomWord = words.get(rand.nextInt(words.size()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Hangman frame = new Hangman();
        Box mainPanel = Box.createVerticalBox();
        frame.setContentPane(mainPanel);
        mainPanel.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        mainPanel.add(panel2);
        mainPanel.add(panel4);
        mainPanel.add(panel3);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't seem to do anything with the random word (`String randomWord`) after assigning to it.

Comment: Your indentation is atrocious.

Comment: try uploading the screen shot to the web (google docs well do) so we could see it full size.

Comment: @elyashiv open image in new tab

Comment: Edited with more focused image, next time crop a bit please :(

Comment: The red underlined line will have an error message associated with it. Either hover the mouse over it or look in the "Problems" tab assuming this is eclipse. We could do with that message.

Answer (score 15):

There are 2 classes called `List` in Java. There is the [java.util.List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) and [java.awt.List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/List.html). Make sure you are not mixing them by accident. I see you are importing `java.awt.*`, so Java thinks you want the java.awt.List, but you want the `java.util.List` version to make it compile. Easiest is to fully qualify the `List` in the problematic statement:

```
java.util.List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: +1 good catch - I would recommend fully qualifying the imports instead of the declaration, but that's just a preference.  Poster is importing java.util.* and java.awt.*

Comment: okay so now I used the java.util.List, the error is gone, but how do i get the word then? I've been working on this problem 2 days straight, my eye's are killing me!

Comment: Try printing the exception you swallow in the `readWord()` method by using: `e.printStackTrace()` Maybe there is a hidden problem there.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem lies in

```
import java.awt.*;
```

The `java.awt` package contains a class called `List`, just like `java.util`, but that is *not* the `List` you want. You're trying to import both of them which causes interference. Either:

- Remove `import java.awt.*;` and add imports for the specific classes you use or
- Qualify the List reference as `java.util.List<String>` or
- Just use `ArrayList<String>` directly

Comment: +1 for use `ArrayList` directly. No reason to use the interface here.

Answer (score 2):

You should import java.util.List explicitly

Comment: +1 for being the shortest possible answer that fixes the problem.

Comment: @Wug, no the shortest answer is: `ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();` Just added `Array` to var declaration.

Comment: @weston Since he's a student, it might be interesting to teach him the difference between interfaces and concrete classes.  The only reason to use ArrayList for the declaration of the variable is lazyness in solving this issue.

Comment: @JoeriHendrickx I was just saying it's not the shortest possible answer! It's not a lazy solution, it's optimal as you could do more work to solve it but there would be no benefit in using the `List` interface in that situation, it's just a local variable after all.

Answer (score 1):

The error say it all: `The type List is ambiguous`

You call two different classes:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

and

```
import java.awt.List;
```

that's being called by `import java.awt.*;`

you have to use a same classes for both of the `List` instances.

for example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
```

or avoid from using `import java.awt.*;` , instead use

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
```

or use the `ArrayList<String>` directly:

```
ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: @SiGanteng ok.. and how could i knew it? i wrote my answer while Wim Deblauwe wrote his.

Comment: @Kuf the compilation error would have stated exactly what the problem is. In Eclipse, clicking on the red warning dot would show it.

Comment: @Kuf also a general point, this is one reason why it's good to keep GUI code and program logic in separate .java classes. Fewer imports in each file -> fewer opportunities for namespace clashes.

Comment: Sorry @Kuf I thought you were the OP